# Running two nodejs apps and one mongo in docker-compose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have two nodeJS applications in separate folders and I am trying to run these two apps with one mongoDB via docker-compose
The following is my docker-compose file.

```
version: "3.8"
services:

  service-a:
    container_name: service-a
    build: ./service-a
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  service-b:
    container_name: service-b
    build: ./service-b
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'

volumes:
  db:
```

when I run **docker-compose up** I am not able to start the three containers at the same time. However, I can do so if I comment out one of the 2 apps. For example, the following is working

```
version: "3.8"
services:

  service-b:
    container_name: service-b
    build: ./service-b
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'

volumes:
  db:
```

How can I make the three containers run simultaneously and both nodeJS connect to the mongo db container?

The logs of the **docker-compose up** is :

```
{
  "t": {
    "$date": "2022-11-15T14:32:20.034+00:00"
  },
  "s": "I",
  "c": "COMMAND",
  "id": 20499,
  "ctx": "ftdc",
  "msg": "serverStatus was very slow",
  "attr": {
    "timeStats": {
      "after basic": 248,
      "after activeIndexBuilds": 364,
      "after asserts": 526,
      "after batchedDeletes": 582,
      "after bucketCatalog": 726,
      "after catalogStats": 1007,
      "after connections": 1143,
      "after electionMetrics": 1434,
      "after extra_info": 1627,
      "after flowControl": 1658,
      "after freeMonitoring": 1715,
      "after globalLock": 1715,
      "after indexBulkBuilder": 1735,
      "after indexStats": 1735,
      "after locks": 1735,
      "after logicalSessionRecordCache": 1750,
      "after mirroredReads": 1750,
      "after network": 1775,
      "after opLatencies": 1775,
      "after opcounters": 1785,
      "after opcountersRepl": 1785,
      "after oplog": 1785,
      "after oplogTruncation": 1795,
      "after readConcernCounters": 1818,
      "after repl": 1903,
      "after scramCache": 2002,
      "after security": 2090,
      "after storageEngine": 2150,
      "after tcmalloc": 2239,
      "after tenantMigrations": 2239,
      "after trafficRecording": 2239,
      "after transactions": 2251,
      "after transportSecurity": 2251,
      "after twoPhaseCommitCoordinator": 2251,
      "after wiredTiger": 2382,
      "at end": 2716
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I have added the logs in the question above!

Comment: Have you tried removing these `stdin_open: true tty: true`?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski yes I did but no luck.

Comment: Are you sure that it's related to docker? Do these services work outside of it?

Comment: I found the root cause. I just increased the resource allocated to docker in my machine and everything is okay now.